# What is the analogue of Date.UTC in .NET

Tags: javascript, .net

Java script has Date.UTC method which is used like that `Date.UTC(2004,3,1)` is there the same in `.NET`?

I was trying to use DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc() but it is returning differs value.

For example if i have this date

javascript `Date.UTC(2004,3,1)` will return this `1075766400000`
but `DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc()` will return this `127175616000000000`

Need help

UPDATE

when i am using this

```
 TimeSpan timeSpan = new DateTime(2004, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
 long milliSeconds = (long)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds; // equal to 1073088000000
```

the `milliSeconds` equal to `1073088000000` but in case of `Date.UTC(2004,3,1)` it is `1075766400000` http://jsfiddle.net/M3aJQ/

the difference is `00:04:27.8400000`

Comment: I suggest looking at the docs. You'll find your answer quicker that way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03ybds8y.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As @Jon Marting says;
[DateTime Constructor (Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32, DateTimeKind)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t882fzc6.aspx)
and use [`DateTimeKind.Utc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921.aspx)

```
public DateTime(
int year,
int month,
int day,
int hour,
int minute,
int second,
DateTimeKind kind
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime` method `ToUniversalTime()` will convert to UTC correctly.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime utc = now.ToUniversalTime();
```

of course for `.Now` in `UTC` you can also use:

```
DateTime utcnow = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc() uses a different epoch to Date.UTC() in JavaScript.  That's why you get different answers.  According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc.aspx) it returns the "number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 midnight, January 1, 1601 A.D. (C.E.) Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)".

Whereas, I believe JavaScript's Date.UTC method returns the number of milliseconds since midnight of January 1, 1970.

You could do it yourself, something like this in .net:

```
        TimeSpan timeSpan = new DateTime(2004, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        long milliSeconds = (long)timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds;
```

Comment: @Joper - Hmmm...you're right, I get 1078531200000? Are you sure the JavaScript result is correct - the value I get matches the results from here - http://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: Yeah - not sure.  There's obviously some Date/Time intricacies we're overlooking!  I noticed your update to the question...I guess we'll just have to wait and see if anyone else can shed any light on it.

Comment: why i didn't get `1075766400000` like in case of javascript `Date.UTC(2004,3,1)` ?

Comment: I am a bit mixed up with dates, i run tests for `Date.UTC(2004,3,1)` but typed `Date.UTC(2004,3,6)`